# Como puedo guardar una base de datos en la nube, con springboot y h2 database?

Tags: java, sql, base-de-datos, spring-boot, h2

Estoy realizando una aplicacion web, en la cual deseo que el cliente en cualquier momento pueda acceder y agregar registros a la base de datos, como puedo hacer para que la bdd este disponible todo el tiempo? Necesito subir la bdd a la nube? Se puede realizar esto con springboot y h2 database? Estoy haciendo la pagina web con JAVA, cualquier sugerencia seria perfecto, gracias.

Mi objetivo es subir una aplicación web al internet y poder modificar y agregar productos y que estos se actualicen.

Comment: A la pregunta actual, la respuesta es: *si se puede*. Te sugiero leer [ask]. Un saludo.

Comment: Jjajajajaja gracias, ya la edite, creo que era medio facil entender que queria saber como hacerlo, saludos

Comment: R/ Dejando una BD accesible para tu aplicación, como sea. R2/ La nube son servidores públicos, es una opción más. Puedes usar tu propio servidor si prefieres, siempre que cumplas con el punto inicial. R3/ Sí, se puede. Sugiero que revises los requerimientos no funcionales de tu aplicación para saber cuánto debes gastar en desplegarla y mantenerla funcionando :)